# IE Opacity Issues with Z-index

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, opacity

I have opacity working in ALL Browsers except IE - the problem in IE (6,7,8) is that the color renders as a SOLID :(

The CSS I am using is legit per the [MS Blog Post on IE Opacity Filter](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/09/08/microsoft-css-vendor-extensions.aspx)

```
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=75)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=75);
```

The weird thing is that I have my elements structured with Z-Index (overlay with 90, lightbox with 100)

When I set the z-index to -1 - IE Opacity starts rendering, but >0 and it appears solid again?

Any ideas!? Its driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a lightbox plugin or are you trying to make your own? You might want to check out slimbox2 and see how he does it since he claims compatibility with all browsers of the rainbow.